# Convert swift repeating array in objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have swift project. I am stuck at one line to convert in objective c

```
var bezierPoints = [CGPoint](repeating: CGPoint(), count: 5)
```

How can I make array in objective C?

Comment: Would a C array `CGPoint bezierPoints[5];` satisfy your needs?

Comment: The best approach depends on what you're actually trying to do. Most likely, you don't need this line at all.

Comment: @MartinR yes its satisfy... thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C you cannot create an array of `CGPoint(s)` because `NSArray` can only contain **objects**.

Anyway you can wrap a `CGPoint` into a `NSValue` so

```
NSArray * points = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointZero],
                    [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointZero],
                    [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointZero],
                    [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointZero],
                    [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointZero],
                    nil];
```

Or as suggested by *@Alexander Momchliov*

```
NSArray * points = @[
                     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointZero],
                     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointZero],
                     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointZero],
                     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointZero],
                     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointZero],
                    ];
```

Comment: Why don't you use an array literal? `@[a, b, c]`

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov: Because I'm forgetting Objective-C :D Thank you!