# Convert a line from Swift to Objective-C

Tags: swift, objective-c

I am trying to convert an extension form Swift to Objective-C. Need to determine an average color from UIImage.
I did almost all but stuck with one line:

```
var bitmap = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 4)
```

this extension from https://www.hackingwithswift.com:

```
extension UIImage {
    var averageColor: UIColor? {
        guard let inputImage = CIImage(image: self) else { return nil }
        let extentVector = CIVector(x: inputImage.extent.origin.x, y: inputImage.extent.origin.y, z: inputImage.extent.size.width, w: inputImage.extent.size.height)

        guard let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAreaAverage", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: inputImage, kCIInputExtentKey: extentVector]) else { return nil }
        guard let outputImage = filter.outputImage else { return nil }

        var bitmap = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 4)
        let context = CIContext(options: [.workingColorSpace: kCFNull])
        context.render(outputImage, toBitmap: &bitmap, rowBytes: 4, bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1), format: .RGBA8, colorSpace: nil)

        return UIColor(red: CGFloat(bitmap[0]) / 255, green: CGFloat(bitmap[1]) / 255, blue: CGFloat(bitmap[2]) / 255, alpha: CGFloat(bitmap[3]) / 255)
    }
}
```

That's what I got in Objective-C:

```
- (UIColor *)averageColorWithUIImage:(UIImage *)image {
    CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:(__bridge CGImageRef _Nonnull)(image)];
    if (!inputImage) {
        return nil;
    }
    CIVector *extentVector = [CIVector vectorWithX:inputImage.extent.origin.x Y: inputImage.extent.origin.y Z: inputImage.extent.size.width W: inputImage.extent.size.height];

    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAreaAverage" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, inputImage, kCIInputExtentKey, extentVector, nil];
    if (!filter) {
        return nil;
    }
    CIImage *outputImage = filter.outputImage;
    if (!outputImage) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSSet *bitmap = [NSSet setWithObjects:0 count:4];
    CIContext *context = [[CIContext alloc] initWithOptions:@{kCIContextWorkingColorSpace : NSNull.null}];
    [context render:outputImage toBitmap:&bitmap rowBytes:4 bounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) format:kCIFormatRGBA8 colorSpace:nil];

        return [UIColor colorWithRed:(CGFloat)bitmap[0]/255.0
                   green:((CGFloat)bitmap[1])/255.0
                    blue:((CGFloat)bitmap[2])/255.0
                 alpha:((CGFloat)bitmap[3])/255.0];
}
```

I got a mistake here:

```
return [UIColor colorWithRed:(CGFloat)bitmap[0]/255.0
                   green:((CGFloat)bitmap[1])/255.0
                    blue:((CGFloat)bitmap[2])/255.0
                 alpha:((CGFloat)bitmap[3])/255.0];
```

Mistake is -

```
Expected method to read array element not found on object of type 'NSSet *'
```

Comment: You know you can call your Swift code from Objective-C, right?

Comment: Does this your answere? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40575365/14733292

Comment: Here there is a sample part https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42539424/how-to-create-ciimage-from-avcapturestillimageoutput-in-swift

Comment: @Sweeper sure I know. But it's not a case.

Comment: @raja-kishan unfortunately - no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you translate the `bitmap` variable to Objective-C:

```
uint8_t bitmap[4] = {};
```

And here is how you pass it to the render method:

```
[context render:outputImage toBitmap:bitmap
    rowBytes:4 bounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)
    format:kCIFormatRGBA8 colorSpace:nil];
```

Note that you do **not** take its address with the `&` operator!

Comment: Thanks @rob. At least it compiled. 
But still I have a problem here:
I'll put it as comment